# Reorder output from Awk, sum first

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following variable:

```
results=$(find . -name "$1" -type f | awk '{n++;print}END{print n " matches found"}')
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
bash$ ./find-file.sh requirements.txt
find: `./LogFiles/WMI/RtBackup': Permission denied
./project-h-squad/requirements.txt: line 11: python-dotenv==0.17.1: command not found
./project-h-squad/requirements.txt
./team-portfolio/requirements.txt
2 matches found
```

The only problem is that I want to display `2 matches found` at the start or the top and the files to be displayed right after. How can I tweak `results` to accomplish this?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: There are several unrelated error messages in the example output. The "command not found" one looks like some other part of your script is trying to execute the text file's contents, which is not only a bug, but potentially a security problem.

Comment: My guess is that the error messages are printed to stderr. The awk output is printed to stdout. If you want to separated theses two streams, redirect them separately, and then display them in any order your like.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `awk` for this; just use `bash` arrays:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' -t results < <(find . -name "$1" -type f -print0)
printf "%d matches found.\n" "${#results[@]}"
printf "%s\n" "${results[@]}"
```

The `readarray` line will robustly store the files returned by `find` in an array (By using a 0 byte between filenames instead of newline, annoying files with newlines in the name won't break things), prints out the length of the array, and then its contents.